# RedactorStyles Plugin Not Working

Tags: redactor, plugin-redactorstyles

I'm having trouble getting the redactorStyles plugin to work. I am running Craft 2.3.2627

Redactor Styles v. 0.2

Here's the json in the json field:

```
 { 
"btnName":"Drop Cap", 
"className":"redactorDropCap", 
"spanClass":"dropCap", 
"forceBlock": "-1"
}
```

I have an external stylesheet, the field is set to: /assets/css/redactorStyles.css

I am not getting any errors in the CP but I also don't get the styles nor do I see the want icon for the plugin dropdown.

Here's the content from the redactor config file:

```
{
buttons: ['html','formatting','bold','italic','unorderedlist','orderedlist','link','image','video'],    
plugins: ['fullscreen','video','styles'],
toolbarFixed: true,
stylesJson: RedactorStyles.stylesJson
```

}

Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong here or if there is a bigger issue? I'm new to Craft.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 1):

Craft 2.3 upgraded Redactor to version 10, which comes with a completely new API for plugins. This broke RedactorStyles which relied on the old API.

I've updated the plugin now, so downloading version 0.3 should make it work with Craft 2.3. Beware that the plugin isn't 100% backwards compatible, due to changes in Redactor and its API, so read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Redactor plugins need a little bit of extra work in Craft. They need to be added through a custom Craft plugin first. Take a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorClips) as an example, particularly where the css and js are stored.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have installed the actual redactor styles plugin itself, and the plugin controls are coming up via the control panel. I don't know if I am not understanding the documentation or not, but as I understand it, I am supposed to put the json snippet into the field for json in the plugin controls and then I can specify an external style sheet which I did at the path above. The thing is, not only is it not displaying the styles I added, but it also is not even showing the styles control for the plugin in redactor even though I added the plugin to my config.

Comment: I tried installing the plugin on my own dev site and it looks like I'm getting the same problem you are. Everything is installing right, and from what I can tell the JSON and CSS are being pushed to the edit entry page. I recommend [reaching out to the plugin developers](https://github.com/aelvan/RedactorStyles-Craft/issues) with this issue!